# How to use a macro such as the returned string is a variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle21c

it works:

```
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{
       select 1 from dual
  }';
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

But if replace the query by a string it doesn't work anymore

```
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
      query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select 1 from dual';
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{
             query
             '};
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

> ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

I've tried a little bit differently

```
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
      query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select 1 from dual';
      ret     VARCHAR (100) := 'q''{' || chr(13) || query || chr(13) || '}''';
BEGIN
  RETURN ret;
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

> ORA-64626: invalid SQL text returned from SQL macro:
> ORA-00903: invalid table name

I've test the value of ret

```
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2  is
      query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select 1 from dual';
      ret     VARCHAR (100) := 'q''{' || chr(13) || query || chr(13) || '}''';
BEGIN
  RETURN ret;
END;
select   f_test() from dual
```

> q'{
> select 1 from dual
> }'

it should work. It's the expected string.

Do I have made a syntax error or is it impossible to create a macro if the returned string is a variable?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d864ec2a560c42f53c470b0462c9ab3a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second function has `q'{...'}` when it should be `q'{...}'`:

```sql
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
      query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'select 1 from dual';
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{query}';
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

However, that still won't work as q-quoted strings are string literals and not template strings and will not embed the variable in-place of the string literal; the `query` variable is unused and the function is effectively:

```sql
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{query}';
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

Which is the same as:

```sql
select count(*) from query
```

This gives you the error:

> ```
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> ```

As there is no table named `query`.

If you want to pass a table name then:

```sql
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
BEGIN
  RETURN 'DUAL';
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

---

Your third query is returning a string literal that contains the text formatted as a q-quoted string literal.

So the query is effectively:

```sql
select count(*) from q'{
select 1 from dual
}'
```

Which gives the error:

> ```
> ORA-00903: invalid table name
> ```

You want to not use a q-quoted string and just use concatenation:

```sql
with FUNCTION f_test return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
  query VARCHAR2(100) := 'select 1 from dual';
  ret   VARCHAR2(100) := chr(13) || query || chr(13);
BEGIN
  RETURN ret;
END;
select count(*) from f_test()
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=451e1be85c64eb83d8b694da88fe54d3)*